# Which gun does the Double Duty talent affect?

Tags: the-division-2

> While holstered, reloading from empty gives you a 20% of your magazine back as free ammo. Can occur once every 30s.

Does this give the gun you're reloading from empty the free 20% ammo, the holstered gun, or maybe both?

Haven't gotten the talent to test myself, but I'm curious because I was taking a look at the **Measured** talent and thinking that if it affects the holstered gun it could be pretty interesting in a weapon swapping build.

Comment: Would be nice if the person who downvoted gave an explanation of why.

Comment: I have a feeling someone is downvoting Division questions generally for some reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Double-Duty:** While the Division agent has **this weapon holstered**, reloading the
>   **other main weapon also reloads this one**. (ar, smg, lmg, bolt-action,
>   sg).

[Source](https://www.gamepur.com/guide/39519-division-2-weapon-gear-talents.html), [source](https://prodigygamers.com/2019/03/12/the-division-2-list-of-all-weapon-talents-and-how-they-work/) and [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OBZIusgYWX8).

Comment: Thank you for the source links.The video only demonstrates the use of one weapon, so it's not valuable for this question, but the other two links seem to explain it pretty well.